# Why is my genetic algorithm not converging?

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, genetic-algorithm

I'm attempting to write a program to find optimal combinational circuits with n inputs and n outputs using a genetic algorithm. The code works but doesn't find the best solution. The algorithm just takes a "good" solution and tries to randomly modify it to get a better one. My question is, Is my approach wrong (shouldn't do so random) or is my code logically wrong?

Git Repository: https://github.com/Umuril/Genetic-Circuits

PS: I just need a look on the code. The code is "commented" and to run just need to: `cd "dir"; make; ./Genetic.out`

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It's very unlikely that people are going to clone your Git repository and look through all of your code.

Comment: There are only 5 files with 1/2 functions each. I think is minimal as example.

Answer (score 1):

In general, evolutionary algorithms do not guarantee that their response is best, but find a good solution. You can find a good solution by your GA first and then use a local search in in your solution neighborhood.

Perhaps Memetic algorithm can help you.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memetic_algorithm

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm won't stop by it self. You have to set some restrains when it has to stop and therefore give you the best solution. Here are the 3 most common ways to make it stop:

- After several number of iterations (generations) e.g. =~ 1000
- After you have a percentage of aberrations in your population e.g. >40%
- When the population avg fitness hits a top value and then starts to deteriorate

Use a combination of all for better results

Comment: I'll use the third approach. But the "top value" is never reached.

Comment: Maybe your fitness function isn't the best for your problem and therefore isn't selecting the best candidates. You mind posting your fitness function and what you try to achieve.

Comment: I'm using Hamming's distance between expected output and the output of my circuit and after that, between the number of logical gates used.

Comment: Sounds good enough. So you never get close enough to a acceptable solution? Could be that your operators are not helping to improve the quality of the generations or that your "good" candidates don't stand out enough to get picked. Try checking your operators and define a better fitness function that make the good candidates stand out better. Could be something like 1/(Hamming(x)) and you maximize that value.